# Django fails to update environment variable from wsgi.py

Tags: python, django, apache, environment-variables

I have a Django application that uses Apache in production. I store the Django secret key value in an external file, from which the key gets applied on startup. I let Apache know the location of the file using SetEnv directive in my application config file:

`SetEnv DJANGO_KEY_LOC /data/www/ref/.myKey`

I've written a function in wsgi.py to get the path from the Apache env variable and apply the key value inside to the SECRET_KEY setting in settings.py. If the code doesn't find that variable it pulls the location from an os env variable I use for dev `DJANGO_KEY='/data/www/ref/.myKey`:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myApp.settings')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myApp.settings'

_application = get_wsgi_application()


def application(environ, start_response):
    try:
        # DJANGO_KEY_LOC set in Apache conf for prod.
        file_loc = environ['DJANGO_KEY_LOC']
        with open(file_loc, 'r') as f:
            os.environ['SECRET_KEY'] = f.read()
    except KeyError:
        # if key missing in environ try dev settings
        print('running in dev environment...')
        dev_file_loc = os.getenv('DJANGO_KEY')
        with open(dev_file_loc, 'r') as f:
            os.environ['SECRET_KEY'] = f.read()
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

The function retrieves the key values just fine, but fails to set os.environ['SECRET_KEY']. The code in settings.py is `SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']`. The app fails to load unless I supply a dummy value for SECRET_KEY beforehand, but the dummy value never gets changed. I tested the set/get code externally in my python interpreter, and it worked fine. What part of getting and setting environment variables inside Django am I missing?

Comment: `return _application(environ, start_response)` That looks to me like you're supposed to be setting the key in `environ`, not in `os.environ`.

Comment: @JohnGordon, good point. I made that change and verified that the `environ` context accepted the key val. Now I need to verify that `SECRET_KEY` in `settings.py` receives the new key as well.

Comment: Setting the key via `environ` doesn't work, either. Additional research hasn't turned up a successful implementation similar to mine, but I did find a 3rd party solution. See below.

Answer (score 1):

I can't yet fully explain why my above code can't set environment variables, but the 3rd party library, [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/), provides a solution. I performed the following steps:

1. install python-dotenv with pip.
2. create a ".env" file in my project's root directory.
3. add a config setting to .env, e.g.: `SECRET_KEY=mysecretkeyval`
4. in my `settings.py` file include `from dotenv import load_dotenv`
5. in settings.py file, call `load_dotenv()`
6. in settings.py, set the application variable: `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')`.

This solution works great, but if I get more specific info on setting (or not) env variables in wsgi.py, I'll update my answer.